# Hystrix.stream and management.context

Tags: spring-cloud

Setting

```
management.context-path = /admin
```

and using

```
@EnableCircuitBreaker
```

makes Hystrix endpoint /admin/hystrix.stream

This becomes an issue when using Turbine to aggregate metrics as its looking for

```
 instanceserver:port/hystrix.stream
```

when discovering instances via Eureka

Any suggestions?

Comment: Hmm, nothing at the moment.  We could put some metadata in eureka, that if there, the turbine eureka locator could use it.

Comment: Created issue https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-netflix/issues/187

Answer (score 0):

Full config for turbine:

```
server.port=8082
spring.application.name=turbine
management.endpoint.health.enabled=true
management.endpoints.jmx.exposure.include=*
management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=*
management.endpoints.web.base-path=/actuator
management.endpoints.web.cors.allowed-origins=true
management.endpoint.health.show-details=always
eureka.client.serviceUrl.defaultZone=${EUREKA_URI:http://localhost:8761/eureka}
eureka.instance.lease-expiration-duration-in-seconds=5
eureka.instance.lease-renewal-interval-in-seconds=5
turbine.aggregator.cluster-config=default
turbine.app-config=google
turbine.cluster-name-expression= new String("default")
turbine.combine-host-port=true
turbine.instanceUrlSuffix.default: actuator/hystrix.stream
```