# Setting logger levels for JHipster Microservice

Tags: logback, jhipster

I am building a microservice architecture for an application and I'm using JHipster v4.5.5 and I get a nice UI on the Gateway for setting logger levels. However, I'm only seeing loggers for the Gateway, and not any of the microservices. Are they supposed to show up in the web UI?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To view and configure loggers for all apps in a JHipster microservice architecture, use the JHipster Registry's Log page (found under Administration in the navbar).  There is a dropdown where you can choose which service to configure.

This was added in v3 of the JHipster Registry.

[image: JHipster Registry Logs page]

Answer (score 0):

No this per JVM but you can configure logging level from the application properties in the registry. See [Managing logging.level using ConfigServer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28198647/managing-logging-level-using-configserver)