# Dynamic | User case Based logging

Tags: java, spring, logging, microservices, spring-cloud-sleuth

Is there any logging framework, which helps me change logging levels dynamically based on the request parameters received ?

If request has a parameter with debug enabled to true, then only it should log, else not.

Does spring sleuth provide this feature in cloud environment?

Comment: Also go through spring actuator logger endpoints through which you can change the levels .https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/production-ready-endpoints.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use Spring Boot & Spring Cloud Config and standard Slf4j logging mechanism. You can check out this answer for more information - [Managing logging.level using ConfigServer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28198647/managing-logging-level-using-configserver)

Answer (score 0):

If you just want conditional logging you would use a [NDC/MDC and a filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7404435/conditional-logging-with-log4j) using the frameworks that support that feature.

If you want something more general then for instance, setup a `com.foo.request` that is set to say `INFO` and a `com.foo.request.debug` that is set to some lower level.  Pick and choose the logger on request parameter.